# How to change the color of QR Code in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, qr-code

I found too many answers for the swift language but not for Objective-C. And I am very poor in converting swift to Objective-C 
Below is my code for QR Code generation:

```
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"];
[filter setDefaults];
NSData *data = [[VizsafeCommonUtil trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:Globals.instance.uuid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1. orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
// Resize without interpolating
UIImage *resized = [self resizeImage:image withQuality:kCGInterpolationNone rate:5.0];
self.imageView.image = resized;
CGImageRelease(cgImage);  

- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image withQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality rate:(CGFloat)rate {
        UIImage *resized = nil;
        CGFloat width = image.size.width * rate;
        CGFloat height = image.size.height * rate;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, quality);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
        resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return resized;
    }
```

I found some code in swift related to my implementation. and if any one can help me to convert below code into Objective-C it will be very helpful.

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
    guard let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor") else { return nil }

    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
    colorFilter.setValue(filter.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1), forKey: "inputColor1") // Background white
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0), forKey: "inputColor0") // Foreground or the barcode RED
    guard let qrCodeImage = colorFilter.outputImage
        else {
            return nil
    }
    let scaleX = imgQRCode.frame.size.width / qrCodeImage.extent.size.width
    let scaleY = imgQRCode.frame.size.height / qrCodeImage.extent.size.height
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)


    if let output = colorFilter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
        return UIImage(ciImage: output)
    }
}
return nil
}
```

So can anyone help me to convert above code into Objective-C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you just need to translate these lines: `filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel"); colorFilter.setValue(filter.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage"); colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1), forKey: "inputColor1") // Background white;  colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0), forKey: "inputColor0")` They really look alike of yours in Objective-C `[filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];`and `filter` and `colorFilter` seems to be the same for you...

Comment: ok what is this `guard`?

Comment: `guard let someVar == something else { return }`, means `if (someVar == nil) { return };` I strongly suggest that you learn a little of Swift, for similar cases, where you need translations. It's not that much difficult. Just understanding what it means, not necessary write it.

Comment: @Larme ok got it. Sure, I will start learning swift. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Objective -C version of my Question:

```
- (void)generateQRCode:(NSString *)userStatus {
    NSData *data = [[VizsafeCommonUtil trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:Globals.instance.uuid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"];

    [filter setDefaults];

    [filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [filter setValue:@"H" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];
    [colorFilter setValue:filter.outputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    if ([userStatus isEqualToString:@"pass"]) {
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
        [self.btnMyHealthPass setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if ([userStatus isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
        [self.btnMyHealthPass setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
        [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
        [self.btnMyHealthPass setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    //CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    CIImage *outputImage = [colorFilter outputImage];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1. orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    // Resize without interpolating
    UIImage *resized = [self resizeImage:image withQuality:kCGInterpolationNone rate:5.0];
    self.imageView.image = resized;
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```